# What is the best way to monitor a http to https redirect on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, monitoring

We have a deployed our Java web application on AWS via Beanstalk. The load balancer is set to forward https (443) to port 80 on EC2, and also forward http (80) to port 80 on EC2. The EC2 instance has Apache running with a rewrite rule that redirects the http traffic to https like so:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/healthcheck$
RewriteRule . https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

This is all working great. Now I want to set up some monitoring to verify periodically that this rule is still in place. (In the past the rule was removed by mistake and we only noticed this by accident). What is the best way to do this?

Edit: we don't have any external system monitor set up, we just use Cloud Watch. Ideally I want to stay within AWS to set this up, e.g. using CloudWatch.

Comment: Just write a custom script for your monitoring system that `curl`s the URL and then examine the output to make sure the redirect is happening correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up [CloudWatch log monitoring](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/WhatIsCloudWatchLogs.html) on your Apache instance monitoring the Apache access log.

Then create a [metric filter](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/MonitoringPolicyExamples.html) in cloudwatch with something like:

`[host, logName, user, timestamp, request, statusCode=301, size, referer, useragent, ...]`

You'll then get a pretty graph in CloudWatch of 301 redirects over time, and you can create CloudWatch alarms to notify when the requests per minute or per hour falls below some threshold.

Another solution might be to set your 301 error document to have a short body, then create a route 53 health check to monitor your redirect URL and search for the body text of your error document. By default the Apache 301 error document should contain "301 Moved Permanently" so you can create a Route53 health check which looks for that string.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever monitoring software you're using already might support that.  Nagios, for example, returns this from check_http:

```
HTTP OK: HTTP/1.1 302 Redirect - 377 bytes in 0.073 second response time
```

You could probably get it to check specifically for the 302 redirect.  (The `-f follow` switch follows the redirect, but that may or may not be what you're looking for.)  Or write a custom script, like EEAA suggested in comments.